# Magento2 - Reuse gift-options.js in other JS file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to reuse the functionality of `module-gift-message/view/frontend/web/js/action/gift-options.js` and use it in one of `Module_Checkout` JS file.

Ex: In `update-shopping-cart.js`.

How do I do this and how to use it?

Comment: Did u get any solution for this ?

Comment: @gajjalasandeep seems like the functionality I wanted was already working and it's just how I defined the product that is not correct

Comment: Actually, I have a requirement where on button click I need to execute the same functionality which gift-options is doing. So, do u have any idea of that ?